# Ironworks and Great Hall combo

Tags: dominion

Just a quick question to be sure we are playing the right way.

Is getting a Great Hall by playing Ironworks let you draw a card and play another action since the Great Hall is both an action card and a victory card?

Reminder:

**Ironworks**

- Action
- cost 4
- Gain a card costing up to 4 Coins. If it is an Action
  card, +1 Action; Treasure card, +1; Victory card, +1 Card.

**Great Hall**

- Action - Victory
- cost 3
- +1 Card, +1 Action, 1 VP

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that's how they work. If the text on the cards isn't enough for you, it also explicitly says it in the rules:

> You get a bonus depending on what type of card you gained. A card with 2 types
>   gives you both bonuses; if you use Ironworks to gain a Great Hall, you will then draw a card (because Great Hall is a Victory card) and may play another Action (because Great Hall is an Action card).

This is really another case of "do exactly what it says on the cards" - it says on Ironworks that if it's an Action you get +1 Action, so you do, and it says on Ironworks that if it's a Victory card, you get +1 Card, so you do.